# Failed to execute MI command: target remote localhost:61234

Tags: debugging, stm32, stm32cubeide

I tried to run a program on `STM32L552ZET6Q` MCU. I use `STM32CubeIDE` for writing programs, `ST-LINK (ST-LINK GDB server)` as debug probe and `SWD` interface.

I successfully compiled the program, but while debugging, I got the following error:

```
    Failed to execute MI command:
    target remote localhost:61234

    Error message from debugger back end:
    localhost:61234: Connection timed out.
    Failed to execute MI command:
    target remote localhost:61234

    Error message from debugger back end:
    localhost:61234: Connection timed out.
    localhost:61234: Connection timed out.
```

I tried to resolve the issue with various suggestions on the web, but I could not solve it. Please, help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with STM32F030C8T6 on macOS, just restarted pc and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

STM32CubeIDE -> Run -> Run Configurations... -> on the left select your config, then -> Debugger -> Reset behaviour -> Type: Connect under reset

This is what worked for me. I also experienced the same problem and couldn't find a solution. After a while I noticed that I could write the FLASH of the chip once after using the STM32CubeProgrammer to completely erase the FLASH of the chip - this suggested that the Watchdog Timer might be the culprit.

Comment: This didn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

What I did and worked again and again is to unplug wires that have output Voltage , for example 3.3V.

*More specific I wanted a communication between nucleo and arduino, where arduino detects if the nucleo is powered up, by detecting output 3.3V. When I unplug this wire upload works perfect otherwise this message appears.*

Answer (score 0):

try reinstall your ST-link driver.
It is for win10 x64: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error with my STM32 NucleoF446ZE board.

This error is shown because the ST-Link isn't able to communicate with the MCU. I solved this error by checking any wiring/soldering mistakes with the board. I eventually found that the board's AVDD was shorted to the board ground through a solder speck. I noticed this because the board was showing a overcurrent condition after turning on.

STM32 boards don't damage often so mostly it's the users wiring/soldering mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In the stm board,there is 4 pins for ST-Link,which you have to short with a clip(its already available in the board).